# Animating the buttons of a app

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I want to animate every buttons of my app, but i want to keep the code clean. I create the following code:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1 ,
            animations: {
                self.mais1Btn.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1) 
            },
            completion: { finish in
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1){
                    self.mais1Btn.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                }
        })
```

But i don't want to copy and paste the code in every IBAction in my code. I don't think that this is the better way to do it. I think of creating a separate class and change the class of the buttons, but i dont think that it's possible, because i have to reference the outlets.

Anyone know a better way to do that?

Comment: you can subclass all the buttons, and add a method to animate them in that subclass. Later u can call that method to peform animation

Comment: but how i create a method the reffers the button? i tried to do "self.transform", but didn't work

Comment: Simply subclass `UIButton` and include an instance method which performs this animation. You can still use them with a Storyboard, just make sure to change their class to your newly made subclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create an extension on the button

```
extension UIButton {
   func doMyAnimation() {
     UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1 ,
        animations: {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1) 
        },
        completion: { finish in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1){
                self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
            }
    })          
   }
}
```

and the simply call `myButton.doMyAnimation()` whenever you want to animate it

Comment: where in my project i create the extension?

Comment: create a new swift file and use the code above and it will work on all UIButtons

Comment: Nice! It worked great. It didn't work before because i forgot to import the UIKit in my file. Thanks for the help.